# Function from Data.Map -> Maybe as a class instance. Confused about how to implement

Tags: haskell, dictionary, option-type

As I was working through [cis 194 (week 5)](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures.html) I came across a problem that introduced two new concepts to me at once, and I'm having difficulty making it, at the very least, output the correct type.

My goal is to implement `var` in the instance declared at the bottom, however, I have never used an instance that was a function before, and nor have I used `Data.Map`, so I'm not very clear on what my solution syntax should even look like.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
import qualified Data.Map as M

class HasVars a where
    var :: String -> a

-- | This instance allows variables to be interpreted as functions from a
--   mapping of variables to Integer values to (possibly) Integer values
instance HasVars (M.Map String Integer -> Maybe Integer) where
    -- not sure how to implement var here
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So when you have

```
class HasVars a where
    var :: String -> a
```

That means that, for any instance `a`, you have a function `var :: String -> a`.

So, if `Map String Integer -> Maybe Integer` is an instance, then that means that you have to provide a function:

```
var :: String -> (Map String Integer -> Maybe Integer)
```

Remember that `(->)` associates from the right, so the parentheses here are optional --

```
var :: String -> Map String Integer -> Maybe Integer
```

So, `var` is a function that takes a `String` and a `Map` and returns a `Maybe Integer`.  Let's write it!

```
instance HasVars (Map String Integer -> Maybe Integer) where
    -- var :: String -> Map String Integer -> Maybe Integer
    var str mp = M.lookup str mp
```

And this works!

---

**edit**: Question in answer

I see that you're wondering why

```
var str = M.lookup str
```

works.  Remember that `M.lookup str` doesn't return a `Maybe Integer`.  It returns a `Map String Integer -> Maybe Integer`.  Which is exactly what `a` should be...exactly what you want.  `var str` is now a function that takes a map and returns a `Maybe Integer`.

`M.lookup str` doesn't have a map, yes, so it can't return a `Maybe Integer`.  But it's a `Map String Integer -> Maybe Integer`.  So `var "hello"` is now a `Map String Integer -> Maybe Integer`.  `var "hello"` gives you a function that takes a map and returns a `Maybe Integer`.  So if you give `var "hello"` a map, like `var "hello" mp`, then you get a `Maybe Integer` :D

Answer (score 1):

So, I've come up with something that at the very least compiles. I had unnecessarily caused myself some confusion when I was attempting to solve this by repeatedly using `Maybe` as a constructor, and staring blankly at the error message that it wasn't defined. `Just` is the constructor for `Maybe`, `Maybe` isn't a constructor; too many times...

Secondly, I completely blanked by using `lookup ...` instead of `M.lookup ...`, leading to unexpected type results.

Those stumblings aside, here's what I tried

```
instance HasVars (M.Map String Integer -> Maybe Integer) where
    var str = M.lookup str -- can be Eta-reduced
```

This compiles, but what doesn't make too much sense to me is that per the instance declaration, shouldn't I be providing a key-value `Map`? `M.lookup` will give back a `Maybe Integer`, but it just doesn't seem like I've given it enough to do that, because it needs a key *and* a `Map`, and I don't seem to have a `Map`. Perhaps my understanding of how class instances work is off.

Comment: Eta expand once and you will see your map.  `var str m = M.lookup str m`. What `var str = M.lookup str` is defining is an equality between functions of one argument; similarly `var = M.lookup` is an equality between functions of two arguments.  These definitions are all just different ways of saying the same thing.